# Long transaction in Mariadb with Spring boot [Socket Exception]

Tags: java, spring, mariadb

we have a large number of data in database and we want to retrieve those data but while we query in mariadb then it takes very large amount of time.

We have Blob type for one of the column of table that is approximate 1.6 MB json data in each row and we try to get those data from table with join query and select query.

so we got below mentioned error..

```
28-02-2022 10:38:28.034 [pool-3-thread-1] WARN  c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.checkException - HikariPool-1 - Connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@3bab7992 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=12937) Connection reset
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:175)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:334)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:386)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.rollback(MariaDbConnection.java:729)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:377)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:563)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:550)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.smartproof.cert.service.CertificateImageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3dbeebd3.scheduleCertificateImageGeneration(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection reset
Query is: ROLLBACK
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:119)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:200)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:328)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:260)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:207)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readResultSet(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1601)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1373)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1323)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:197)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
28-02-2022 10:38:28.041 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor.completeTransactionAfterThrowing - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:301)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.readNextValue(SelectResultSet.java:390)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.fetchAllResults(SelectResultSet.java:310)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.<init>(SelectResultSet.java:177)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readResultSet(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1625)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1373)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1323)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:252)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:164)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1123)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:171)
28-02-2022 10:38:28.043 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:567)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:550)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.smartproof.cert.service.CertificateImageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3dbeebd3.scheduleCertificateImageGeneration(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:563)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=12937) Connection reset
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:175)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:334)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:386)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.rollback(MariaDbConnection.java:729)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:377)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection reset
Query is: ROLLBACK
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:119)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:200)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:328)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:260)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:207)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readResultSet(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1601)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1373)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1323)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:197)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

is anyone any idea about it?

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

Comment: @Kayaman we are increase memory from 512MB to 1024MB but issue is still there.

Comment: @Kayaman Not sure but how to resolve it and how to make code workable?

Answer (score 0):

increase max_allowed_packet in config files